# WCF Service - HttpContext.Current.User not logged out using FormsAuthentication on Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a basic Silverlight Business Application which also hosts a WCF service. The service is secured to require Administrators role.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1()        
    {            
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    }

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}
```

Oddly, after logging out of the Silverlight Application, I was still able to replay the service call to DoWork() successfully using Fiddler.

Setting a breakpoint on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;` showed that the `HttpContext.Current.User` was still holding the previously authenticated users identity.

What is going on here?

Comment: How is your AuthenticationService implemented? How do you log out (using WebContext)?

Comment: The standard Business application template uses a subclass of AuthenticationBase. A further note: adding <location path="myservice.svc"><system.webServer><authorization><add accessType="allow" roles="Administrators" /> fixes the problem, but it is a little bit icky as it might be misconfigured in the future.